# tikz/pgf and `\maxof` broken since 3.0.1a

Tags: tikz-pgf, calc

The following example works well tikz up to 3.0.0 (TL 2014 and probably 2015), but breaks since tikz 3.0.1a (till now):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
Start image
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, inner ysep=0.3ex]
  \path let \p1 = (0,4), \p2 = (0,8) in node (foo) at (0,0+\maxof{\y1}{\y2}) {Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   m
l.8 ...,8) in node (foo) at (0,0+\maxof{\y1}{\y2})
                                                   {Hello};
?
```

By copying only one file (`pgfmathparser.code.tex`) from the old installation to the new one the example starts working again.

Is this a known problem?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the link. I thought I exchange the `\maxof{}{}` with `max(,)` but that didn't work either.

Comment: `(0,{0+ max(\y1,\y2)})`  works for me (at least it doesn't gives and error).

Comment: Huu, some comments got lost here ... strange

Comment: Can you link documentation to the `max` function? It doesn't seem to work for my use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the newer pgf-version the compability code for calc has been moved from  `\pgfmathparse@` to a more "inner" command and this breaks in the token processing. If I add the code again to `\pgfmathparse@` it works again:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd\pgfmathparse@{\let\maxof=\pgfmath@calc@maxof}{}{\fail} %and so on
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Start image
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, inner ysep=0.3ex]\tracingmacros=1
  \path let \p1 = (0,4), \p2 = (0,8) in node (foo) at (0,{0+\maxof{\y1}{\y2}}) {Hello};
  \path let \p1 = (0,4), \p2 = (0,8) in node (foo) at (0, 0+\maxof{\y1}{\y2}) {Hello};
  \path let \p1 = (0,4), \p2 = (0,8) in node (foo) at (0,{0+ max(\y1,\y2)}) {Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I don't know the *why* the code was moved, so it could have unwanted side-effects. It is also possible that there is a better place for the code somewhere in the middle of the two locations.

### Edit

I found the commit which made the change. It was done while implementing a "fast lane":

> added automatic "fast lane" to math parser:
>
> if the input is a number without units, it will return that as-is. Reduces
>   typesetting time down to 66% for huge scatter plots and has just 1% overhead
>   for math intensive figures.

Imho the code wasn't moved by purpose into the inner command but more or less accidental  as the new inner command was written by changing the existing `pgfmathparse@` and moving the calc-compability code back to `pgfmathparse@` should work fine.

Comment: I don't think there was an intention to support `calc` package in the first place.

Comment: @percusse: The code is there already in 2014: `% Stuff for calc compatiability.
    \let\real=\pgfmath@calc@real
    \let\minof=\pgfmath@calc@minof
    \let\maxof=\pgfmath@calc@maxof` and so on.